# glibc sscanf segmentation fault on RHEL8, same code is working on RHEL 5,RHEL6 and RHEL7

Tags: scanf, glibc, coredump

We have a legacy C application that running correctly on RHEL5,RHEL6 and RHEL7.
But the same application is crashing on RHEL 8, the call stack is pointing to crash in glibc library function sscanf.

Below is the call stack top-

```
*#0  0x00007f437767696e in __GI__IO_vfscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f437768a991 in vsscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f4377684f48 in sscanf () from /lib64/libc.so.6*
```

All arguments passed to sscanf are valid, having correct values, we confirmed in gdb.
The same code is working in older RHEL versions.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> all arguments have correct values

If we are to trust you on that, you shouldn't have a crash inside `sscanf`, but you do.

There are two things I would try if I had this problem:

1. Verify with [valgrind](https://valgrind.org) that your program doesn't have heap corruption elsewhere.
2. Install libc debuginfo package ([instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/developer_guide/intro.debuginfo)) so you can see exactly *where* inside `__GI__IO_vfscanf` your program crashes.